# I am unable to type polish characters when connecting via ssh

Tags: 12.04, server, putty, character-set

I'm running ubuntu server 12.04 on VirtualBox.

When connecting via console, I am able to type in Polish characters just fine (both on the command line as well as in VIM).

When connecting via putty, I am unable to type polish chars (AltGr+a produces "a" instead of the polish char)

I would like the system to remain in English however to also be able to type polish characters via ssh.

On putty, under window>translation I set remote char set to UTF-8. I also selected the consoles font with Central European script.

I tried everything I could find on the Internet (installing the polish language pack, dpkg-reconfigure console-setup) but nothing seems to work.

This is what I have for my locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Thank you very much for all your help!

---

I figured it out and here is the answer (I can't post it since I don't have enough reputation, spent nearly half a day trying to figure this out and it turned out to be so simple...). Here is the answer:

I fugured it out, thank you very much for all your help nonetheless!

I have win7 and I had my keyboard set to US. I had to go to control panel > region and language > keyboards and languages and add Polish programmer keyboard (adding Polish keyboard but with US layout didn't work). I also set the location to Poland (was US).

This is my work laptop that got rebuilt recently hence I didn't have this set. Polish chars via putty seem to be working perfectly fine now! :)

Comment: While new users can't post answers too fast, they can post them. Would you please post what you did to fix this problem as an answer? I believe you will be able to accept the answer as well in a couple of days, and you should.

Comment: will do John, just trying to figure out how everything works around here :), thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, thank you very much for all your help nonetheless!

I have Windows 7 and I had my keyboard set to US.

I had to go to *Control panel* → *Region and language* > *keyboards and languages* and add **Polish programmer keyboard** (adding Polish keyboard but with US layout didn't work). I also set the location to Poland (was US).

This is my work laptop that got rebuilt recently hence I didn't have this set. Polish chars via putty seem to be working perfectly fine now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct locales on the machine?
You can find supported locales in by running

```
$ less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
```

Locales mentioned in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` will be regenerated when running

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Otherwise your problem may be your SSH client.
If you are using Putty, try the following:

1. Go to [Connection > Data] and change 'Terminal-type string' to "linux".
2. Go to [Window > Translation] and change 'Remote character set' to UTF-8.

Comment: I am not sure that this is an issue with locale settings, I tried changing those but this doesn't help, I am still unable to type polish characters via ssh (putty) but even with the locale configuration as posted in the original question above I seem to be able to type those no problem via console (logging in via virtualbox window), any help would be greatly appreciated as I seem to be stuck with this really badly

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I changed the 'Terminal-type string' and already had the 'Remote character set' set to UTF-8 but still getting the same behavior

Comment: What characters are we talking about?

Comment: śćąłęńóżź, I posted the solution I found in my question